# A .NET Core website won't build on OS X - "Assets file '.../obj/project.assets.json' not found."

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build a .NET Core application that I created on Visual Studio 2017 on Windows on Visual Studio 2017 for Mac.

I've run a 'dotnet restore' which seems to complete correctly. However, when I build, I get the following:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/build/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(154,5): error : Assets file '.../obj/project.assets.json' not found.
>   Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.  [.../TME.PatternLibrary.csproj]

And several `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

How can I build the .NET Core project on Mac OS X?

Comment: Please make sure you have proper .net core version on OSX (even beta). VS 2017 uses new project type where `json` files are replaced with `xproj`files.

Comment: I have the following -

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.1.0
  Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86

Comment: Run `dotnet.exe --version` on OSX.

Comment: dotnet --version = 1.0.1

Comment: Have you tried with ´Update-Package –reinstall´?

Comment: I have tried updating and reinstalling the packages from Visual Studio 2017 and the terminal, however the packages reinstall / update fine but there are build errors.

Comment: Can you please share the csproj file

Comment: It looks like your mac isn't registering you have .Net core 1.1.0 installed if your output from dotnet --version is 1.0.1. This will most likely be the issue. have you downloaded and manually installed .net core 1.1.0 ? https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

Comment: Correct answer @BigTallJosh I would mark correct if it weren't a comment. Thanks

Comment: @JamieGilbert Glad it's sorted, added as an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your Mac isn't registering that you have .NET Core 1.1.0 installed if your output from `dotnet --version` is 1.0.1. This will most likely be the issue. If you download and manually install .NET Core 1.1.0, this should solve your problem.

You can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos).